# Flask-Security login invalid password issue

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, flask-security, flask-bootstrap

I am implementing flask-security for simple registration and login, yet for some reason, I have not been able to understand or find, why after successful registration and successful login when I try to again login I get 'invalid password'.

I am using flask-bootstrap, sqlite3, python 3.6.4, pyenv+virtualenv,

Here is the structure of the application:

```
body-mass-index/
    run.py
    application/
        __init__.py
        templatess/
            index.html
            home.html
            security/
                register_user.html
                login_user.html
```

Here is the init file:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Configuration
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = \
        '*id4)fbbiyd*57oa18da3^t0$)m%ti#9ua+t^ihd4z9t*x%&sx'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/bmi.db'
    app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = os.urandom(32)
    app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
    app.config['SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL'] = False
    app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW'] = '/bmi'
    app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGOUT_VIEW'] = '/'
    app.config['SECURITY_POST_REGISTER_VIEW'] = '/bmi'
    app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False

    # Create database connection object
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # Define models

    roles_users = db.Table(
        'roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

    class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
        __tablename__ = 'role'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
        description = db.Column(db.String(255))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Role> {}'.format(self.name)

    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        __tablename__ = 'user'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(255))
        active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
        confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
        roles = db.relationship(
            'Role',
            secondary=roles_users,
            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<User> {} {}'.format(self.mail, self.email)

    # Setup Flask-Security
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)

    @app.before_first_request
    def before_first_request():
        # Create any database tables that don't exist yet.
        db.create_all()

    # Initialize bootstrap
    Bootstrap(app)

    # Debug = True to enable the toolbar
    toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # Views

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/bmi', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def bmi():
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['user_id']).first()
        return render_template('bmi.html', user=user.email)

    return app
```

Here the login file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}

{% block title %} {{ _('Login') }} {% endblock %}

{% block mynav %}

    <li><a href="{{ url_for_security('register') }}">Register</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for_security('login') }}">Login</a></li>

{% endblock mynav %}

{% block mycontent %}

    <h1>{{ _('Login') }}</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
        {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email, class="form-control", placeholder="example@email.com") }}
        {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password, class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
        {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
        {{ render_field(login_user_form.next, class="btn btn-primary") }}
        {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit, class="btn btn-primary", value="Login") }}
    </form>

{% endblock mycontent %}
```

I appreciate the time and effort, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the definition of the User class for the **secondary** was badly done, as well as the implementation of the **roles_users** table

Also, the sequence for the **first request** was not proper, it has now been fixed!

It now all works well, this sample application integrates Flask with React, enjoy!
[github repo for bmi challange](https://github.com/fbenavides69/body-mass-index)